`org-delete-backward-char` (bound to `DEL` in Org mode) sometimes does not work
Using emacs 26.1 with org mode 9.1.9.
More and more often, as I am editing an org file, the backspace key stops working, ie it does not remove characters or blank lines to the left of the cursor.
For example, I sometimes used backspace to delete blank lines between headings. If backspace stops working, I find that moving the cursor up a line or 2, seems to restore backspace functionality.
Backspace does consistently work in any other software package.
When I do C-h k and then press the backspace key then 1) "DEL" flashes for a split second 2) I get a left screen display of a long list of things entittled "Concept Index" 3) I get another screen saying "DEL (translated from ) runs the command org-delete-backward-char (found in org-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘org.el’. It is bound to DEL.
Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to later versions because I am using a log term support linux distro that has older versions in the repo.
I did search on "backspace" in this emacs forum and I do see a lot of posts re backspace, but they seem to be about a consistent undesired behaviour, while mine is intermittent, and so I don't think these posts would be helpful.

Does it work consistently outside of Emacs? Does it work consistenly in modes other than Org mode? What is it bound to (C-h k <BACKSPACE> to find out)? Finally, both emacs 26.1 and Org mode 9.1.9 are outdated: can you upgrade to Emacs 29.4 and Org mode 9.6.15 and try again?

Hi, backspace does consistently work in any ofther software package.

I only use org mode in emacs and so I do not have any experience with backspace in other emacs modes.

When I do C-h k and then press the backspace key then 1) "DEL" flashes for a split second 2) I get a left screen display of a long list of things entittled "Concept Index" 3) I get another screen saying "DEL (translated from ) runs the command
org-delete-backward-char (found in org-mode-map), which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘org.el’. It is bound to DEL.

Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to later versions because I am using a log term support linux distro that has older versions in the repo and there is no way to over-ride that.

Please try it in some other Emacs mode: it's important to determine whether it's an Emacs problem or an Org mode problem. The C-h k information is as expected. Thank you for providing it, but as a general principle, you should edit your question and add all relevant information to it: comments are not meant for that - they are not searchable and they can get lost.

Can you reproduce the problem with emacs -Q? If not, then your init file is at fault: bisect it to finger the culprit.

@NickD I tried emacs -Q and then this problem does not occur. I will look into how to bisect my init file as you suggest, thanks for your help. I have added my comments to my original post.
